# Why <img> element is not taking the exact width that I tell with CSS?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-design

I'm selecting an `<img>` element with CSS and applying a `width` to it, but, when I inspect the computed value of the generated element by the browser (the generated `<img>`), I see a different value.

Furthermore, I'm kind of confused, Am I specifying the width (with CSS) of the element's *content-box* instead the width of the image itself?

I'd share to you an example:

```html
<div class="carousel-image carousel-image-fachada" id="mapaFachada">
  <img src="/images/slider/slide-home-mapa-fachada.png" alt="mapa norte-centro país Nexus" width="450" height="auto">
</div>
```

```css
.carousel-image-fachada {
  @media (min-width: bulma.$desktop) {
    display: flex;
  }
  & > img {
    @media (min-width: bulma.$widescreen) {
      width: 700px;
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the computed value of the generated element:

[image: img element width with CSS]

In this example, is not respecting the `700px`. Instead, the final result is `515.297px` wide.

How do I tell with CSS that this image should be exactly `700px`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is a flex child in this situation, so it can be shrunk to fit the default (or defined) settings of its flex parent in the particular circumstances. To avoid that automatic shrinking, add `flex-shrink: 0;` to the CSS rule for the `img`

Comment: I've added `flex-shrink: 0;` in the *flex-container* and now works. So, this is a situation where we have to keep in mind flex-box's rules. Disabling automatic shrinking is the key!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's caused by the `max-width: 100%;` rule. Try to remove it or to put it at `max-width: auto;`

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you remove the `width` attribute from the `img` tag? Like this:

```
<div class="carousel-image carousel-image-fachada" id="mapaFachada">
  <img src="https://c4.wallpaperflare.com/wallpaper/500/442/354/outrun-vaporwave-hd-wallpaper-preview.jpg" alt="mapa norte-centro país Nexus" height="auto">
</div>
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/christian2033/pen/eYeqqPG)

Comment: Attribute style is not applying because the selector `.carousel-image-fachada > img` wins.

Answer (score 0):

The component you have selected in your Dev Tool, might not be the image. Because I believe `img` element could not have properties such as `font-size`, `font-weight`, `text-align` etc. Make sure you select the `img` element in your browser and add the screenshot that shows you have selected the right element.